# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in... Need to change string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have been reading some of the other questions here but I can't find one that fully explains how I should fix it. I am new to JSON and don't fully understand it all. I am creating a dynamic table where people can input injuries to different body parts. I want to be able to manipulate this data using JSON. I am using an alert to check I can get each individual bodypart/injury. When I click on the usejson button I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in - [then json code]

From my understanding it seems that it doesn't recognise the JSON as an object but as a string. Being new I don't fully understand that. Is anybody able to fix my code so that it alerts each bodypart?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<!--all 4 below need for bootstrap 4 - including poppers-->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
   <body>
        <style>
            table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td,
    th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
   </style>



    <table id="injuriestable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="heading">
            <th id="bodypart">Body Part</th>
            <th id="injuries">Injuries</th>
            <th id="edit">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Test input: <input id="injuryinput" type="text"><br>
<button data-bodypart="head" class="addinj">Head</button>&nbsp&nbsp<button data-bodypart="shoulder" class="addinj">shoulder</button>&nbsp&nbsp<button data-bodypart="knee" class="addinj">knee</button>&nbsp&nbsp<button data-bodypart="foot" class="addinj">foot</button><br/>
<button id="arraytest" >Get Json Array</button>
<button id="usejson" >Use Json</button>


<div id="jsonarray"></div>

<script>
    //adding a new row
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //adding a new row   
        $(".addinj").click(function() {
            var bodpart = $(this).data("bodypart");
            var datas = $("#injuryinput").val();
            //checks if row exists and if does updates/if not creates one
            if ($("#part" + bodpart).length > 0) {
                $("#injuries" + bodpart).html(datas);
            } else {
                $('#injuriestable').append('<tr id="part' + bodpart + '"><td>' + bodpart + '</td><td id="injuries' + bodpart + '">' + datas + '</td><td><button data-bodparts="' + bodpart + '" class="injurybutton">' + bodpart + '</td></tr>')
            }
        });

       //get json
        $('body').on('click', '#arraytest', function() {
            var table = document.getElementById("injuriestable");
            var tableArr = [];
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                tableArr.push({
                    bodypart: table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML,
                    injuries: table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML,
                });
            }
            var jsonstring = (JSON.stringify(tableArr));
            $("#jsonarray").html(jsonstring);
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#usejson', function() {
            var data = $("#jsonarray").html();

            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                alert(data[i].bodypart);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: JSON is a format. It's a way to write an Array or Object in textual form. You can use it to transmit complex data over a "text-only" communications channel. The textual form is based on the way you write an Array literal or Object literal in JavaScript, hence the name: `JavaScript Object Notation`. You do not need it at all for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also: never store data in HTML elements for later use. Keep everything in `var`s, and use HTML to display it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h3udwjos/ (the code actually uses `JSON.stringify` to compare Objects)

Comment: Aah that works thanks for your help. At the moment the jsfiddle creates a new row if the injuries is different. How do I change this code so that it only creates a new row if the bodypart is different? Also how do I add data attributes to the buttons I am creating?

Comment: 1. `.some(injury => injury.bodypart == injToAdd.bodypart)` 2. Look up the jQuery method [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think use can use:

```
$('body').on('click', '#usejson', function() {
        //var data = $("#jsonarray").html();
        var data = JSON.parse($("#jsonarray").html());

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            alert(data[i].bodypart);
        });
    });
```

But i don't understand that why you send json to html and then get it from html.

Comment: Awesome thanks. This works great. Yeah I should be using variables instead. Will do that going forward